# Bash variable under a mysql query

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script to clean wordpress based websites easily. I've a MySQL query to run with respect to a bash variable which I'm unable to figure out.

Since most of wordpress security plugins change database's table prefix so I want to use:

```
db_prefix=$(cat wp-config.php | grep "\$table_prefix" | cut -d \' -f 2)
```

to know of the exact table prefix which is in use & then use this MySQL query:

```
mysql -D${db_name} -u${db_user} -p${db_pass} << "EOF"
SELECT *
FROM  `wp_options`
WHERE  `option_name` LIKE  'template';
EOF
```

Now I want to use `$db_prefix` as variable on 3rd line of MySQL query by replacing `wp_` with `$db_prefix`.

Is there any way to do so?

EDIT: I didn't know that it's that active, I really appreciate all of contributers, you'll see me contributing here too.

Bash script is live here now: https://github.com/saadismail/wp-clean

Thanks to all of you guys & girls...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must do as String

```
mysql -D${db_name} -u${db_user} -p${db_pass} -e "SELECT * FROM wp_${db_prefix}_options WHERE  option_name LIKE  'template';"
```

and it work.

or use backslash at the end of line

```
echo "SELECT * \
FROM  wp_${db_prefix}_options \
WHERE  option_name LIKE  'template " | mysql -D${db_name} -u${db_user} -p${db_pass}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
the one-liner shell script that tries to extract `db_prefix` is incorrect.
This way should work:

```
db_prefix=$(grep '^$table_prefix' wp-config.php | cut -d_ -f3)
```

After you run this command, verify it:

```
echo $db_prefix
```

Perhaps you didn't know how to embed the `${db_prefix}` variable inside the here-document?
Like this: `wp_${db_prefix}_options`.

But to be able to embed variables, then the starting `EOF` marker of the here-document cannot be enclosed in double-quotes, `"EOF"`, because then variables will not be interpolated.

But then, if you change `"EOF"` to `EOF`, a remaining issue is the backticks, which would be executed by the shell as sub-shells, but you need to include them literally. One way to fix that is to omit them, as they are not really necessary.

Putting it together:

```
mysql -D${db_name} -u${db_user} -p${db_pass} << EOF
SELECT *
FROM  wp_${db_prefix}_options
WHERE  option_name LIKE  'template';
EOF
```

Comment: Actually I don't have any knowledge of mysql queries, I just copied that query from phpmyadmin. Tried updated script but this time it's just ignoring that variable & giving this error: ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'wp30616db_16958._options' doesn't exist

wp30616db_16958 is database name here.

Comment: I see. Actually the way you extract the value of `db_prefix` from `wp-config.php` is broken too. I updated my post with the fix, see at the top.